# Actionscript 3 sprite clear with alpha

Tags: flash, actionscript, adobe

I wanna clear sprite with 0.1 transparency, but sprite.graphics.clear() doesnt have that option. It needs to be cleared constantly every frame. How can I do that? i tried with filled rectangle on the whole stage with transparency 0.1, but my game is slowing down every frame.

Comment: You want to do `sprite.alpha = 0.1` ?

Comment: my blue sprite is drawn every frame on new position, but prevous arent deleted. And i wanna draw white rectangle over whole screen so that all prevous sprites are 0.1 more alpha, so every new sprite has bigger alpha and sprite that i have drawn first has smallest alpha. So if i draw 10 blue sprites on screen on random positions, 1st's alpha should be 0 (invisible), second 0.9, third 0.8 and so on.

Comment: I don't understand what you are looking for, but why you don't use `sprite.graphics.clear()` every time you want to draw ? you can use also `removeChild(sprite)`.

Comment: @Dominik Your question is unclear. You should rewrite it.

Comment: Sorry my question is unclear, solved it, but thanks for help anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you should put all the sprite into a Vector and you manualy remove them when you need.

```
    private var vec:Vector.<Sprite> = new Vector.<Sprite>();

    private function update():void
    {
        // reduce the alpha of all other sprites
        // check all other sprites from the newest to the oldest (so we can make a splice without getting an index error in case of there is other sprites to remove)
        for(var i:int = this.vec.length -1; i >=  0; i--)
        {
            this.vec[i].alpha -= 0.1;

            if(this.vec[i].alpha == 0)
            {
                if(this.contains(this.vec[i]))
                {
                    this.removeChild(this.vec[i]);
                }

                // we clear the sprite so it doesn't use any memory
                this.vec[i].graphics.clear();

                // remove the sprite from the vector
                this.vec.splice(i,1);
            }
        }

        // create and draw the new sprite you want to add
        var addingSprite:Sprite = new Sprite();
        addingSprite.graphics.beginFill(0x005500);
        addingSprite.graphics.drawCircle(0, 0, 10);

        this.addChild(addingSprite);                    // add the sprite to the stage

        this.vec.push(addingSprite);                    // add the sprite to the vector so you can reduce his alpha easily
    }
```